# What causes the "filterUsers is not defined" error in this Svelte App?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I am working on a small Svelte application, for learning purposes (Im new to Svelte).

The application displays a JSON of users from randomuser.me API in a Bootstrap 4 table.

I am currently working the application into components.

In `App.svelte` I have:

```
<script>
    const apiURL = "https://randomuser.me/api/";
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import { fade, fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    import { flip } from 'svelte/animate';
    import Search from './Search.svelte';
    let users = [];
    $:filteredUsers = users;
    
     onMount(() => {
        getUsers();
        filterUsers();
    });
    
    const getUsers = () => {
        let getFrom = "&results=20&inc=name,location,email,cell,picture";
        fetch(`${apiURL}?${getFrom}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => users = data.results);
    };
    
    const deleteUser = (user) => {
        let itemIdx = filteredUsers.findIndex(x => x == user);
        filteredUsers.splice(itemIdx,1);
        filteredUsers = filteredUsers;
    }
</script>
```

The search feature was moved to its own component:

```
<script>
    export let stringToMatch = '';
    export let filteredUsers = [];
    
        export const filterUsers = () => {
        filteredUsers = users;
    
        if(stringToMatch){
            filteredUsers = users.filter(user => {
                return user.name.first.toLowerCase().includes(stringToMatch.toLowerCase())
                    || user.name.last.toLowerCase().includes(stringToMatch.toLowerCase())
                    || user.location.city.toLowerCase().includes(stringToMatch.toLowerCase());
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="search p-2">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search..." bind:value="{stringToMatch}" on:input="{filterUsers}">
</div>
```

Even though I have exported the variables from `Search.svelte` and imported te search component into the `App.svelte` component, I get a `filterUsers is not defined` error, as can be seen in the **[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a0b0c71a600f4c40bb9b685439378d16?version=3.28.0)**.

Why does that happen? What's the fastest fix?

Comment: You need to be in a `<script context="module">` to be able to export functions that you can import in other component.

Comment: @johannchopin Can you be more precise? Maybe post an answer I could validate. I am learning Svelte and I could use more details. Thanks.

Comment: Yes sure sorry I will write asap ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search component should be responsible for emitting the search term or you can write a filtered function and pass it to Search, But you're calling child function in parent. As far I know `export` is defers in svelte. It means `Child` component expecting a `prop` not actually exporting the variables. you can read more about component communication here: https://svelte.dev/docs#1_export_creates_a_component_prop.

I have made some changes on your REPL. you can find it here.

https://svelte.dev/repl/9da70df5e25646aabc5c37355b82c4a3?version=3.28.0

Comment: Your solution is very profesional, but not very explicit. Anyway, thank you.